# Como converter imagem de cinza para RGB?

Tags: imagem, algoritmo

Para converter uma imagem em RGB para escala de cinza é relativamente fácil, basta fazer uma combinação linear( ou a média) dos 3 canais. Por exemplo :

```
Gray = 0.3*R +0.59*G +0.11*B
```

Pela expressão acima se obtém uma matriz em tons de cinza.

Minha dúvida é : como obter as matrizes R, G e B a partir da matriz Gray para se obter uma imagem colorida a partir de uma em tons de cinza ?

Comment: Não obtém. A transformação é só de ida

Comment: Basicamente abrindo num programa de edição de imagens e colorindo "conforme o gosto"

Comment: Para que fique mais facil entender o problema: 16 + 2 + 22 = 40, correto? Partindo do número 40, como é que você poderia saber quais foram os três números somados? Não tem como, pois tem infinitas combinações de três números que resultam em 40 quando somados. A conversão para cinza é quase a mesma coisa (muda um pouco a fórmula, tem um range numérico mais definido, mas que em nada ajuda sem uma análise de outros fatores)

Comment: Colorir de vez em quando faz bem pra mente. :)

Answer (score 1):

Como dito nos comentários, não tem como recuperar os valores originais apenas a partir do valor cinza.

O que você pode fazer é armazenar tanto o valor em cinza quanto o RGB.

Por exemplo, você terá uma classe Pixel (pseudo codigo):

```
class Pixel {
  byte R
  byte G
  byte B
  byte Gray

  public Pixel(byte R, byte G, byte B) {
    this.R = R
    this.G = G
    this.B = B
    this.Gray = mean([R, G, B]) // Escala de cinza a partir da média dos valores RGB
  }
}
```

Com essa classe você tem todas as informações necessárias pra exibir a imagem colorida ou cinza. O programa vai usar mais memória, mas é o preço que se paga por manter a informação da cor original.

Answer (score -1):

Se `Gray = 0.3*R +0.59*G +0.11*B`

é só fazer Gray=R=G=B que a imagem no ponto RGB(i,j,k) terá as 'mesmas cores' da imagem cinza.

No math/octave:

```
pkg load image;
imagemGray = imread('gray.png'); %ler arquivo gray

for i = 1 : 3
 imagemRGB(:,:,i) = imagemGray(:,:);
endfor
```